# Qt: Is there a way to get a mac file path from indoor url?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, qt5, osx-yosemite, pyqt5

When dropping a file on my QWidget from Finder I am getting a URL with the inode:

```
file:///.file/id=6571367.1385460/
```

This is a known bug in the current Qt versions on Yosemite, as shown here:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40449

Is there a way to work around this by converting the url to a valid file path using Qt lib or Python 3 libs? I am using PyQt and am trying to program a workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: But ti's also fixed in Qt 5.4.1, so can't you just wait for it (or download the snapshots if you're impatient)?

Comment: I didn't realize this was fixed. If it is mentioned in the issue tracker then I must have missed it. Thanks!

Comment: It says "Status: Done" and "Fix Version: 5.4.1", and reports the commit that fixed it.

Comment: I now realize my confusion. 5.4.1 is not released yet, and so I imagine this fix is just in the snapshots.